# Complex regex in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, validation

I am trying to add a regular expression in my AngularJS controller that validates the four following conditions in a text input box:
A) `name (space) name`,  B) `name,(comma) name`, C) `123456789` (max of 9 digits) D) `123-45-6789`

I created the following regex:
1) validation: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,\-]+[(?<=\d\s]([a-zA-Z0-9]+\s)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ /`,

This is close to what I want with the exception of formatting the last four digits and limiting digits to a max of nine characters.

I also tried combining the following regex per my research to no avail:
2) validation: `/^([0-9]{8,9})$/ + /^([A-z'\/-])+[\s]+([A-z'\/-])+$/ + /^([A-z'\/-])+[\s]*[\,]{1}[\s]*([A-z-\/'])+$/ + /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/`,

3) validation: `/^([0-9]{8,9})$/ | /^([A-z'\/-])+[\s]+([A-z'\/-])+$/ | /^([A-z'\/-])+[\s]*[\,]{1}[\s]*([A-z-\/'])+$/ | /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/`,

4) validation: `new RegExp('(' +  /^([0-9]{8,9})$/ + ") | (" + /^([A-z'\/-])+[\s]+([A-z'\/-])+$/ + ") | (" + /^([A-z'\/-])+[\s]*[\,]{1}[\s]*([A-z-\/'])+$/ + ") | (" +  /^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$/ + ')')`,

I have three questions:

- Is it possible to create one regex that validates these four conditions?
- Am I not combining these correct?
- Or should I abandon this regex mission and just create a separate function to perform my validation?

Comment: Maybe I'm understanding something wrong, but why wouldn't just combining them with | work?

Comment: I would think it would work but for some reason the system seems to ignore the regex after the | symbol

Comment: Maybe because your first regex has unclosed parenthesis?

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure I understand,  '(' + /^([0-9]{8,9})$/ + ") isn't that a closed parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you: `^([a-zA-Z]+(?:-\/)?[,\/]?\s+[a-zA-Z]+(?:-\/)?|\d{1,9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$`

```js
const validate = input => /^^([a-zA-Z]+(?:-\/)?[,\/]?\s+[a-zA-Z]+(?:-\/)?|\d{1,9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$/.test(input)

const testData = ["123", "name space", "John Doe", "John/ Doe", "Doe, John", "John", "name, ", "John   Doe", "John-/   Doe", "John-/, Doe-/", "sdf", "123-45-6789", "1234567890" ,"name , surname"]
for (const input of  testData){
  console.log(`${input} ${validate(input)}`)
}
```

Comment: this is really cool but it allows one name to be processed.  so John should be invalid criteria but John Smith or Smith, John should be good.

Comment: @Eddie ill fix it in second

Comment: @Eddie now it's fixed as you wanted but i have one question it has to bo one space or one or more ?

Comment: That's a great question.  Just one space is allowed between names or Smith, John.

Comment: @Eddie check now it's propably okay

Comment: This is great, thanks so much.  Also, I just realized that Smith-Doe should be valid.

Comment: Unfortunelty no :/ i learned myself by practice and answering people questions :D

Comment: - and / should be allowed with names.  Also, do you have any favorite resources regarding regex I can check out.

Comment: thanks, I need to practice more.  John-/ Smith-/ is a valid name, so long as there are no spaces, so John -/ is not ok.  How can I do that with the regex?

Comment: got it.  I modified [a-zA-Z] to [a-zA-Z-/].  Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem im here to help :)

Comment: could you show me matching one like this `example` becacuse i dont see what is one

Comment: Yes, I was just about to post, I modified just a tad: ^([a-zA-Z\-//]+[,\/]?\s[a-zA-Z\-//]+|\d{1,9}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})$/  and this allows for John-/ Smith-/ as well as John Smith and Smith, John.  I believe that is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]+,?[ ]+[a-z]+)|(?:\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})|(?:\d+))$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/mJxbFb/2).

---

Broken down, it reads:

```
^                          # match beginning of the line
(?:                        # non-capturing parenthesis
    (?:[a-z]+,?[ ]+[a-z]+) # a-z then comma (optional) space then a-z again
    |                      # or
    (?:\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4})  # the number format with dashes
    |                      # or
    (?:\d+)                # only numbers
)
$                          # match the end of the line
```